# Error when converting fractional input to int

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, numbers, integer

In my factorial computation program, I get a number from the user

```
n=float(input("n=")) #sign
```

I wanted to change it so that the number would be converted to an integer instead of a float:

```
n=int(input("n=")) #sign
```

But this doesn't work when I input a float number like "4.5". The error code is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\factorial of n natural numbers.py", line 5, in <module>
    n=int(input("n="))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4.5'
```

I've converted the int number to float since I decided to enter a float number but it looks like it hasn't been converted or what...

The program still works with the first version, but what's the problem there? What is the difference between those conversions?

Comment: you can't cast anything thats not just numbers as an int, meaning that inputs like `4.5` will raise that error right away. however, you CAN convert ANY float into an int, ONCE it has already been cast as a float. that is because calling `int()` on a float really just truncates that float to the decimal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function returns a string object:

```
>>> n = input("n = ")
n = 4.5

>>> x
>>> '4.5'
>>> type(n)
<class 'str'>
```

As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org) states, when you don´t pass a string instance representing a so called [*integer literal*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integers) to Pythons [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) function, you will get an `ValueError`.

```
>>> int(n)
Traceback (most recent call last):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4.5'
```

To avoid this you could catch this error or convert the string first to a floating point number (using [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) -- so the number type is not important -- and afterwards to an `int`:

```
>>> int(float(n))
    4
```

Hope this helps :)